# Calculating position via net force, different dts yield different answers

Tags: haskell, physics

I'm trying to write a simulator for charged and massed objects based on just calculating the net force on each object then finding the change in position across the period of time specified by the user.

However, I'm finding that when I change the dt, the change in position is drastic, when it shouldn't change significantly, decreasing the dt should just let the position converge on the correct answer.

For instance, with objects at the Cartesian coordinates (1, 0, 0) and (-1, 0, 0), with masses of 9e-31 (mass of electron) and a charge of 1 Coulomb (not the charge of an electron, I know), run for 0.1 seconds and a dt of 0.01 seconds, there is a total change of position of 2048 meters for each object. However, run for 0.1 seconds and a dt of 0.001 seconds, there is a change in position of about 1.3e30 meters. This seems rather outrageous to me, but I can't find any issues in the parts that use dt.

The code I'm using (c/p'd to avoid any possible changes)

```
import Data.List

main = print $ mainprog
    where

        mainprog = runUniverse makeUniverse 1 0.1

type Length = Double
type Mass = Double
type Charge = Double
type Time = Double



type Vector = (Double, Double, Double)
type Position = Vector
type Velocity = Vector
type Acceleration = Vector
type Force = Vector

data Widget = Widget {pos :: Position, mass :: Double, charge :: Double, velocity :: Velocity} deriving (Eq, Show, Read)


--utils
toScalar :: Vector -> Double
toScalar (x, y, z) = sqrt (x ^^ 2 + y ^^ 2 + z ^^ 2)

toUnit :: Vector -> Vector
toUnit (x, y, z) = (x / scalar, y / scalar, z / scalar)
   where 
       scalar = toScalar (x, y, z)

add :: Vector -> Vector -> Vector
add (x1, y1, z1) (x2, y2, z2) = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2, z1 + z2)

mult :: Vector -> Double -> Vector
mult (x, y, z) k = (k * x, k * y, k * z)

diff :: Vector -> Vector -> Vector
diff (x1, y1, z1) (x2, y2, z2) = (x1 - x2, y1 - y2, z1 - z2)


--calcs
gForce :: Widget -> Widget -> Force
gForce (Widget pos1 mass1 _ _) (Widget pos2 mass2 _ _) = mult unitForce scalarForce
    where
        unitForce = toUnit posdiff
        scalarForce = (g * mass1 * mass2) / (radius ^^ 2)
        g = 6.674e-11
        radius = toScalar posdiff
        posdiff = diff pos1 pos2


eForce :: Widget -> Widget -> Force
eForce (Widget pos1 _ charge1 _) (Widget pos2 _ charge2 _) = mult unitForce scalarForce
    where 
        unitForce = (toUnit posdiff) 
        --necessary to determine attraction vs repulsion, whereas        gravitational is always attractive
        scalarForce = ((abs (k_C * charge1 * charge2)) / (radius ^^ 2)) * (signum charge1) * (signum charge2)
        k_C = 8.988e9
        radius = toScalar posdiff
        posdiff = diff pos1 pos2


netForce :: [Force] -> Force
netForce = foldl add (0, 0, 0)

toAccel :: Force -> Widget -> Acceleration
toAccel f (Widget _ mass _ _)  = mult f (1/mass) 

newVeloc :: Velocity -> Acceleration -> Time -> Velocity
newVeloc v a dt = add v (mult a dt)

newPos :: Vector -> Velocity -> Time -> Vector
newPos s v dt = add s (mult v dt)



newWidget :: Widget -> Position -> Velocity -> Widget
newWidget (Widget pos1 mass charge vel1) pos2 vel2 = Widget pos2 mass charge vel2

tUniverse :: [Widget] -> Time -> [Widget]
tUniverse widgets dt = zipWith3 newWidget widgets poses vels
    where

        netMassForces = map (\w -> gForcePrime w (widgets \\ [w])) widgets
        gForcePrime w ws = netForce $ map (gForce w) ws

        netElectricForces = map (\w -> eForcePrime w (widgets \\ [w])) widgets
        eForcePrime w ws = netForce $ map (eForce w) ws

        volds = map velocity widgets

        polds = map pos widgets

        accels = zipWith toAccel (map netForce (zipWith (\a b -> a : [b]) netMassForces netElectricForces)) widgets

        vels = zipWith (\v a -> newVeloc v a dt) volds accels

        poses = zipWith (\s v -> newPos s v dt) polds vels


makeUniverse :: [Widget]
makeUniverse = [(Widget (-1, 0, 0) 1 1 (0, 0, 0)), (Widget (1, 0, 0) 1 1 (0, 0, 0))]

runUniverse :: [Widget] -> Time -> Time -> [Widget]
runUniverse ws t dt
    | t <= 0 = ws
    | otherwise = runUniverse (tUniverse (inelasticCollide ws) dt) (t-dt) dt  



inelasticCollide :: [Widget] -> [Widget]
inelasticCollide [] = [] 
inelasticCollide (w:[]) = [w]
inelasticCollide (w:ws) = (combine w (sameposes w ws)) : (inelasticCollide $ ws \\ (sameposes w ws))
    where
        sameposes w ws = filter (\w' -> pos w == pos w') ws

        combine :: Widget -> [Widget] -> Widget
        combine = foldl (\(Widget pos mass1 charge1 veloc1) (Widget _ mass2 charge2 veloc2) -> Widget pos (charge1 + charge2) (mass1 + mass2) (newveloc mass1 mass2 veloc1 veloc2))
        --inelastic collision, m1v1 + m2v2 = m3v3 therefore v3 = (m1v1 + m2v2)/(m1 + m2)
        newveloc m1 m2 v1 v2 = ((v1 `mult` m1) `add` (v2 `mult` m2)) `mult` (1 / (m1 + m2))
```

The issue I know is in the tUniverse function, probably in some calculation of either acceleration, velocity, or position (accels, vels, or poses). I've tried changing toAccel, newVeloc, and newPos by multiplying each by the inverse of dt, but it didn't significantly change the outputs.

Feel free to ignore inelasticCollide, I could probably replace it with the id function, but I just left it in because it will be relevant at some point.

EDIT: I've updated the code to fix the incorrect calculation of acceleration, the switching of mass and charge in inelasticallyCollide, and the double counting with dpos/dvel, but I'm still finding that I'm getting an error of by a magnitude of 10. For instance, with a charge of 1 C for each, I got ~10^8 for dt = 0.01 and ~10^7 for dt = 0.1 and with a charge of 0.01 C for each, ~250 for dt = 0.01 and ~65 for dt = 0.1.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm reading this right, but usually the acceleration is force *divided* by mass. -- For free electrons, 0.1s seems to be a long time. Also, every Euler method requires very extremely small step sizes to give reliable results. Try to use higher order integration methods.

Comment: `toAccel` as written has a type error. `mult f mass` compiles, but I think `f=ma -> a=f/m` so there might be an issue there. Just trying to get some sane output to start from I tried changing `makeUniverse` to `[Widget (0,0,0) 0 0 (0,0,0)]` which did result in `[Widget (0,0,0) 0 0 (0,0,0)]`, but when I tried `[Widget (1,0,0) 0 0 (0,0,0)]` (that is, providing only an initial position) the result was `[Widget (1.2676506002282294e30,0,0) 0 0 (0,0,0)]` which I would not expect. I would recommend simplifying things to find a smaller case that is easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't change that changing dt has an inordinate effect that it shouldn't have, thinking naively.

Comment: @JackBrandt Per your update, I tried a range of `dt`s and do observe the factors you're describing. It certainly seems related to `netElectricForces`. Barring any calculation issues, I think the result may be due to the charge values of 1 being absolutely enormous. Using values such as 1e-9 to 1e-5 the results become quite reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was going to be some error, I just didn't realize it would be so drastic. It's good to know it was a human error, so I can move on with my project.

Comment: @JackBrandt I think I somewhat confirmed it... because the starting positions are so close and the charge values so large, the first tick of electric force value is on the order of 1e9, and then immediately drops to the order of 1e-2 for subsequent ticks, making the final distance overwhelmingly dependent on that first value. Since the application is multiplied by `dt`, the actual effect of the first tick was proportional to `dt`, which you had adjusted by a factor of 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the "obvious" issue is that `newWidget` assumes `dpos` and `dvel` are deltas, but when it's called in `tUniverse` `poses` and `vels` have actually already done the addition.

To debug I had rewritten things to use `newtypes` thinking that perhaps there was a mismatch somewhere. There did turn out to be an issue of masses and charges being transposed in `inelasticCollide` but that didn't matter for my test case. The way I found this issue was by adding the `trace`s and seeing that the object's position component doubled each tick when the velocity component was 1.

I have no idea whether any calculations are accurate otherwise.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Data.List

import Debug.Trace (trace)

main = print $ runUniverse makeUniverse 0.1 0.01

newtype Length = Length {unLength::Double}
newtype Mass = Mass {unMass::Double} deriving (Num,Eq,Show)
newtype Charge = Charge {unCharge::Double} deriving (Num,Eq,Show)
newtype Time = Time {unTime::Double} deriving (Num,Eq,Ord,Fractional)

type Vector = (Double,Double,Double)
newtype Position = Position {unPosition::Vector} deriving (Eq,Show)
newtype Velocity = Velocity {unVelocity::Vector} deriving (Eq,Show)
newtype Acceleration = Acceleration {unAcceleration::Vector}
newtype Force = Force {unForce::Vector} deriving (Eq,Show)

data Widget = Widget {pos :: Position, mass :: Mass, charge :: Charge, velocity :: Velocity} deriving (Eq, Show)

--utils
toScalar :: Vector -> Double
toScalar (x, y, z) = sqrt (x ^^ 2 + y ^^ 2 + z ^^ 2)

toUnit :: Vector -> Vector
toUnit (x, y, z) = (x / scalar, y / scalar, z / scalar)
   where 
       scalar = toScalar (x, y, z)

add :: Vector -> Vector -> Vector
add (x1, y1, z1) (x2, y2, z2) = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2, z1 + z2)

mult :: Vector -> Double -> Vector
mult (x, y, z) k = (k * x, k * y, k * z)

diff :: Vector -> Vector -> Vector
diff (x1, y1, z1) (x2, y2, z2) = (x1 - x2, y1 - y2, z1 - z2)


--calcs
gForce :: Widget -> Widget -> Force
gForce (Widget (Position pos1) (Mass mass1) _ _) (Widget (Position pos2) (Mass mass2) _ _) = Force (mult unitForce scalarForce)
    where
        unitForce = toUnit posdiff
        scalarForce = (g * mass1 * mass2) / (radius ^^ 2)
        g = 6.674e-11
        radius = toScalar posdiff
        posdiff = diff pos1 pos2


eForce :: Widget -> Widget -> Force
eForce (Widget (Position pos1) _ (Charge charge1) _) (Widget (Position pos2) _ (Charge charge2) _) = Force (mult unitForce scalarForce)
    where 
       unitForce = (toUnit posdiff) 
       --necessary to determine attraction vs repulsion, whereas        gravitational is always attractive
       scalarForce = ((abs (k_C * charge1 * charge2)) / (radius ^^ 2)) * (signum charge1) * (signum charge2)
       k_C = 8.988e9
       radius = toScalar posdiff
       posdiff = diff pos1 pos2


netForce :: [Force] -> Force
netForce = Force . foldl add (0,0,0) . map unForce

toAccel :: Force -> Widget -> Acceleration
toAccel f (Widget _ mass _ _)  = Acceleration (mult (unForce f) (unMass mass))

newVeloc :: Velocity -> Acceleration -> Time -> Velocity
newVeloc v a dt = Velocity (add (unVelocity v) (mult (unAcceleration a) (unTime dt)))

newPos :: Position -> Velocity -> Time -> Position
newPos s v dt = Position (add (unPosition s) (mult (unVelocity v) (unTime dt)))

newWidget :: Widget -> Position -> Velocity -> Widget
newWidget w@(Widget pos1 _ _ vel1) dpos dvel = w { pos=Position ((unPosition dpos)),velocity=Velocity ((unVelocity dvel)) }

tUniverse :: [Widget] -> Time -> [Widget]
tUniverse widgets dt = zipWith3 newWidget widgets (trace (show poses) poses) (trace (show vels) vels)
    where
        netMassForces = map (\w -> gForcePrime w (widgets \\ [w])) widgets
        gForcePrime w ws = netForce $ map (gForce w) ws

        netElectricForces = map (\w -> eForcePrime w (widgets \\ [w])) widgets
        eForcePrime w ws = netForce $ map (eForce w) ws

        volds = map velocity widgets

        polds = map pos widgets

        accels = zipWith toAccel (map netForce (zipWith (\a b -> a : [b]) netMassForces netElectricForces)) widgets

        vels = zipWith (\v a -> newVeloc v a dt) volds accels

        poses = zipWith (\s v -> newPos s v dt) polds vels

makeUniverse :: [Widget]
makeUniverse = [Widget (Position (1,0,0)) (Mass 0) (Charge 0) (Velocity (1,0,0))] -- , (Widget (1, 0, 0) 9e-31 1 (0, 0, 0))]

runUniverse :: [Widget] -> Time -> Time -> [Widget]
runUniverse ws t dt
    | t < 0 = ws
    | otherwise = runUniverse (tUniverse (inelasticCollide ws) dt) (t-dt) dt

inelasticCollide :: [Widget] -> [Widget]
inelasticCollide [] = [] 
inelasticCollide (w:[]) = [w]
inelasticCollide (w:ws) = (combine w (sameposes w ws)) : (inelasticCollide $ ws \\ (sameposes w ws))
    where
        sameposes w ws = filter (\w' -> pos w == pos w') ws

        combine :: Widget -> [Widget] -> Widget
        combine = foldl (\(Widget pos mass1 charge1 veloc1) (Widget _ mass2 charge2 veloc2) -> Widget pos (mass1 + mass2) (charge1 + charge2) (Velocity (newveloc (unMass mass1) (unMass mass2) (unVelocity veloc1) (unVelocity veloc2))))

        --inelastic collision, m1v1 + m2v2 = m3v3 therefore v3 = (m1v1 + m2v2)/(m1 + m2)
        newveloc m1 m2 v1 v2 = ((v1 `mult` m1) `add` (v2 `mult` m2)) `mult` (1 / (m1 + m2))
```

Comment: Thanks! That appears to change the error to be of about a magnitude of 10. Just wondering, what's the purpose of doing the newtypes? Is it just for type safe reasons? I thought that just data would work for it.

Comment: @JackBrandt The `newtypes` are just for additional type safety, yes. Like previously, if you wrote a function of `Force -> Mass -> Acceleration`, because all of those types were just synonyms for `Double` there was nothing stopping you from mistakenly passing, for example, a value that actually represented a `Velocity` (or transposing the arguments). I did that replacement first to see if any logical errors fell out (the only one that did was in `inelasticCollide` where the variable names didn't match the position in the `Widget` deconstruction).